# How to count the number of lines in an Objective-C string (NSString)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, newline, enumeration

I want to count the lines in an NSString in Objective-C.

```
  NSInteger lineNum = 0;
  NSString *string = @"abcde\nfghijk\nlmnopq\nrstu";
  NSInteger length = [string length];
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
  while (range.location < length) {
      range = [string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, 0)];
      range.location = NSMaxRange(range);
      lineNum += 1;
  }
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

well, a not very efficient, but nice(ish) looking way is

```
NSString *string = @"abcde\nfghijk\nlmnopq\nrstu";
NSInteger length = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] count];
```

**Swift 4:**

```
myString.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

Comment: Thank you ! ! 
In Above case, how to code?
Sorry I'm begginner for Programming

Comment: Bear in mind that if the string is very long, this will be *much* less efficient than code like what you posted in the question, since it will create a new string object for every line. Be sure you understand how important performance is where you are doing this, and what the upper bound on the string size will be.

Answer (score 46):

Apple recommends this method:

```
NSString *string;
unsigned numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [string length];

for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength; numberOfLines++)
    index = NSMaxRange([string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
```

See the [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html). They also explain how to count lines of wrapped text.

Comment: Probably would be a good idea to initialise the string for the sample, infinite loop without a nil check.

Comment: The only thing this account for was strings that started/ended with a new line. To fix this I added the following:
  

`NSString *string = @"this is \nyour string\n"; NSInteger numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [string length]; for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength; numberOfLines++) index = NSMaxRange([string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]); if([string hasSuffix:@"\n"] || [string hasSuffix:@"\r"]) numberOfLines += 1; if([string hasPrefix:@"\n"] || [string hasPrefix:@"\r"]) numberOfLines += 1; return numberOfLines;`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take into account the width of the text, you can do this with TextKit (iOS7+):

```
func numberOfLinesForString(string: String, size: CGSize, font: UIFont) -> Int {
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: string, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])

    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: size)
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.textStorage = textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

    var numberOfLines = 0
    var index = 0
    var lineRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    for (; index < layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++) {
        layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
    }

    return numberOfLines
}
```