# Is there a way to count the number of lines of a NSString ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count the number of lines in an Objective-C string (NSString)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085524/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-an-objective-c-string-nsstring)

Is there a way to count the number of lines of a NSString ?

```
NSString * myString = @"line 1 \n line 2 \n";
```

lines = 3;

thanks

Comment: You should Refer Text Layout Programming Guide. [Counting Lines of Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

Comment: @Patrick please search on SO and google before posting question on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
NSString * myString = @"line 1 \n line 2 \n";
NSArray *list = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"No of lines : %d",[list count]);
```

Answer (score 9):

Beware `componentsSeparatedByString` is *not* smart enough to detect between mac/windows/unix line endings. Separating on `\n` will work for windows/unix line endings, but not classic mac files (and there are some popular mac editors which still use these by default). You should really be checking for `\r\n` and `\r`.

Is addition, `componentsSeparatedByString:` is slow and memory hungry. If you care about performance, you should repeatedly search for newlines and count the number of results:

```
NSString * myString = @"line 1 \n line 2 \n";

int lineCount = 1;
NSUInteger characterLocation = 0;
NSCharacterSet *newlineCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
while (characterLocation < myString.length) {
  characterLocation = [myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:newlineCharacterSet options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(characterLocation, (myString.length - characterLocation))].location;

  if (characterLocation == NSNotFound) {
    break;
  }

  // if we are at a \r character and the next character is a \n, skip the next character
  if (myString.length >= characterLocation &&
      [myString characterAtIndex:characterLocation] == '\r' &&
      [myString characterAtIndex:characterLocation + 1] == '\n') {
    characterLocation++;
  }

  lineCount++;
  characterLocation++;
}

NSLog(@"%i", lineCount);
```

Comment: The latter solution will also correctly handle CRLF sequences, whereas `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` will return an empty component for each such sequence.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHosey I thought the exact opposite of what you're saying is true, but I did some tests and you're right. My code was broken on windows newlines. I have edited my answer to delete the one-line example, and updated the long/fast example to check for `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString * myString = @"line 1 \n line 2 \n";
int count = [[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count];
NSLog(@"%d", count);
```