# What's the fastest way to find the number of spaces in an NSString?

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSString and I want to find the number of spaces in it.  What's the fastest way?

Comment: Basically the same problem as [counting lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1287145/30461), just without the wrinkle of supporting multiple line separators.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not the fastest to execute, but the fastest to type up:

```
[[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count]-1
```

Comment: What if there are two or more continuous spaces?

Comment: According to [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), "Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty strings in the result."

Comment: You are correct. Your solution is much more elegant than mine. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work. It might be possible to optimize, but you only need to worry about that if it's absolutely necessary.

```
NSUInteger spacesInString(NSString *theString) {
    NSUInteger result = 0;
    if ([theString length]) {
        const char *utfString = [theString UTF8String];
        NSUInteger i = 0;
        while (utfString[i]) {
            if (' ' == utfString[i]) {
                result++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it seems like it should work off the top of my head.

```
int spacesCount = 0;

NSRange textRange;
textRange = [string rangeOfString:@" "];

if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    spacesCount = spacesCount++;
}

NSLog(@"Spaces Count: %i", spacesCount);
```