# Get the number of lines in UILabel iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm seeing lots of deprecated answers for this question:

How do I calculate the number of lines in use in a `UILabel` based of its set text?

I know that I need to set the `UILabel` to have bounds that resize with word wrapping. In this way, I could detect the height of my `UILabel` and adjust an `NSLayoutConstraint` for the height of my `UITableViewCell`. Basically my problem plain and simple is:

How can I determine my **UILabel**'s number of lines in use(based of `descriptionLabel.text`) or height in order to resize My **UITableView**'s **UITableViewCell**s which contain my **UILabel**.

Currently I have used this code:

```
descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 270, 65)];
descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "calculate"? You don't *calculate* it, you *set* it.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is calculate the number of lines in use. As in, the number of lines that the length of `descriptionLabel.text` creates.

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085524/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-an-objective-c-string-nsstring/30040905#30040905) what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm looking for a SIMPLE solution that would involve using only the UILabel. I will default to attempting this string method if this is too complicated. I feel like this should be easy.

Comment: @Chisx I think you don't need to get the number of lines. Instead, you can calculate the height what the label need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem very simply with this code:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(290.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize requiredSize = [descriptionLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
[descriptionLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, requiredSize.width, requiredSize.height)];
NSLog(@"THE HEIGHT OF THIS DESCRIPTIONLABEL IS: %f",cell.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = ... // your attributed string
CGFloat width = 300; // whatever your desired width is
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
//rect is the height of UILABEL which u can used as height of label or table view row or etc
```

Comment: Does it have to be an `NSAttributedString`? Or can I accomplish the same effect by simply placing my NSString in the line where you create the variable `CGRect rect`

Comment: it must be NSAttributedString you can place your string in NSAttributedString